# How to get single items count in a slice with go?

Tags: go

For example, this is a slice:

```
[1, 2, 3, 3, 4]
```

want to get single data `1, 2, 4` 's count and return `count = 3`.

Maybe remove duplicate items(include itself) is an idea, but didn't find suitalbe method.

---

What I tried:

```
  func removeDuplicateItems() {
      intSlice := []int{1, 2, 3, 3, 4}
      fmt.Println(intSlice)

      keys := make(map[int]bool)
      list := []int{}
      for _, entry := range intSlice {
          if _, value := keys[entry]; !value {
              keys[entry] = true
              list = append(list, entry)
          }
      }

      fmt.Println(list)
  }
```

Got

```
[1 2 3 3 4]
[1 2 3 4]
```

Comment: What have you tried? Include your code. What specific problem do you need help with?

Comment: @Flimzy I added what I tried.

Comment: you expect 1,2,4. Why is there no 3 in your list?

Comment: @apxp I don't want `3` but want single items.

Comment: I would change the map definition. Do not just check with `bool` make it an `int` and count how often the value is inside your slice.

Comment: Here you go: https://play.golang.org/p/ESFLhC4VC-l

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just changed your function a little bit:

```
func removeDuplicateItems() {
    intSlice := []int{1, 2, 3, 3, 4}
    fmt.Println(intSlice)

    keys := make(map[int]int)
    list := []int{}
    for _, entry := range intSlice {
        keys[entry]++
    }
    for k, v := range keys {
        if v == 1 {
            list = append(list, k)
        }
    }

    fmt.Println(list)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/ESFLhC4VC-l

At this point the list is not sorted. If you want to sort your list afterward you need to use the `sort`package.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose a really easy & quick way to get the count of unique values would be to use a map:

```
data := map[int]bool{}
cnt := 0 // count of unique values
for _, i := range intSlice {
    if dup, ok := data[i]; !ok {
        // we haven't seen value i before, assume it's unique
        data[i] = false // add to map, mark as non-duplicate
        cnt++ // increment unique count
    } else if !dup {
        // we have seen value i before, but this is only the second time
        cnt-- // unique count goes down here
        data[i] = true // mark this value as known duplicate
    }
}
```

At the end of this loop, you'll have `cnt` with the count of unique values, and you can iterate the map `data` for all keys with value `false` to get the unique values that you found in the slice. All keys combined basically are the values in the slice, de-duplicated.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I want the single count. Not include duplicate data itself.